# Conditional output processing in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Having the following class:

```
class Test {
  [MyAttr]
  public string Name;
}
```

How can I extend [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) if I need to trim values of all properties marked with `MyAttr` to specific length? Seems I can't do that in custom `JsonConverter` as I need access to `MemberInfo` representing the origin property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deeper reading the documentation and source code it looks like contract resolver is the way to go:

```
public class MyCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (value == null) {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        string str = value.ToString().Substring(1, 2);
        writer.WriteValue(str);
    }
}

public class MaskContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.CustomAttributes.Any(x => typeof(MyAttr).IsAssignableFrom(x.AttributeType)))
            property.Converter = new MyCustomConverter();
        return property;
    }
}
```

As easy as pie!